# How to load a file in Kotlin REPL

Tags: kotlin, read-eval-print-loop

According to `:help` in Kotlin REPL I can load a file by `load:` command.

```
>>> :help
Available commands:
:help                   show this help
:quit                   exit the interpreter
:dump bytecode          dump classes to terminal
:load <file>            load script from specified file
```

But loading the file fails like this.
The `Rational.kt` exists current directory.

```
>>> load: "Rational.kt";
error: unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)
load: "Rational.kt";
```

Neither `load: Rational.kt` nor `load: "Rational.kt"` works.
How can I load a file in REPL? 
I couldn't find an example for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try without the quotes:

`>>> :load Rational.kt`

Comment: Your answer make me notice that I was using `load:` instead of `:load`. Thanks.